# nodeJS passing variable to variable

Tags: node.js, variables

Based on extensive searching, had thought backtick would do the trick, but no dice.  At a lost for words why the code variable won't get passed into another variable.  Used backticks, ${variable} and no dice.  Ideas?

```
exports.stripeConnect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var code = req.query.code;
    const ref = admin.database().ref(`/stripe_advisors/testing`);
    return ref.update({ code: code });

    var request = require('request');

    var dataString = `client_secret=sk_test_8gxfc3KHDoPC4pyFvitYcwf1&code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code`;

    var options = {
            url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
            method: 'POST',
            body: dataString
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            }
    }

    request(options, callback);
});
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You have a mass of code here that doesn't seem relevant to the problem, and which won't run independently.  If I break it down to what I *think* you are getting at, replacing variables you didn't provide with hard-coded data, then [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/lopekopapa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: That's the entire code for the Firebase function.  Problem is clearly stated, how do I pass the var code into datastring.

Comment: "That's the entire code for the Firebase function." — Yes, which is (a) Not minimal because it is the entire code for the function and (b) Not complete because it can't be run independently. (Note that "complete" means it needs to demonstrate your problem, not be all of your code, so adding hardcoded input is often helpful)

Comment: "how do I pass the var code into datastring" — The way you are doing. See my previous comment. In particular the link at the end where I said I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the value of variable 'code', concatenated in the variable 'dataString', for that you can use the concatenation operator(+). In your case:

```
dataString='client_secret=sk_test_8gxfc3KHDoPC4pyFvitYcwf1&code='**+code+**'&grant_type=authorization_code';
```

I wrote a test code based on what you have written:

```
var code = 'Hello';
var dataString = \`${code}, World\`;

console.log(dataString);
```

The Output is : Hello, World

So in the above code dataString should be having the value in code variable just print the variable and test.

you can't pass query string in body, please check if what you are passing in body is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another poster in another question, learned that the string wasn't the issue @ all and it's JS async nature.  Below is the working code to use Firebase Functions to do Stripe Connect onboarding process.  Enjoy!

var rp = require('request-promise');

```
//Stripe Connect
exports.stripeConnect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
var code = req.query.code;
const ref = admin.database().ref('/stripe_advisors/testing');
var dataString = `client_secret=sk_test_8gxfc3KHDoPC4pyFvitYcwf1&code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code`;
var options = {
        url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        body: dataString
};

rp(options)
.then(parsedBody => {
    return ref.update({ code: code });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
});

});
```